# How to pull multiple sub-table data as a single table data in JavaScript with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, html-table, cheerio

I want to download the whole table data from [this webpage](https://finviz.com/calendar.ashx).  It has five sub tables having its own thead and tbody each, under 'table[class="calendar"]'.  My codes below can pull all thead texts and tbody texts as whole, but doesn't group them by each sub table.

I want to pull thead texts and tbody texts from each sub tables and then combine them to one table so that I can have the whole organized table data just in the same arrangement as the webpage shows. How can I do that?

```js
function test() {
  const url = "https://finviz.com/calendar.ashx";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);

  var thead = $("thead")
    .find("th")
    .toArray()
    .map(el => $(el).text());
  var tableHead = [],
    column = 9;
  while (thead.length) tableHead.push(thead.splice(0, column)); //Convert 1D array to 2D array
  console.log(tableHead);

  var tcontents = $("body > div.content")
    .find("td")
    .toArray()
    .map(el => $(el).text());
  var idx = tcontents.indexOf("No economic releases");
  if (idx) tcontents.splice(idx + 1, 0, "", "", "", "", "", ""); // Add empty elemets to match number of table columns
  var tableContents = [],
    column = 9;
  while (tcontents.length)
    tableContents.push(tcontents.splice(0, column)); //Convert 1D array to 2D array
  tableContents.pop(); // remove last empty array
  console.log(tableContents);
}
```

My expected output is:
[image]

Comment: `$('thead').find('th')` will find all the `th` contained in all the `thead` on the page, in one go. And similar issue with `$('body > div.content').find('td')`, for the `td` elements. If you want to process the data of each table separately - then you should start with a loop over those tables. And then, select the relevant elements inside the current one.

Comment: How can I choose each table and loop them?   That's what I'm lacking.

Comment: `$('table').each()`- https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Can you show your exact expected output?

Comment: I added my expected output as an image to the post.

Comment: Seeing `const` is great, but why `var` instead of `let`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution as below.  I'm using Google Apps Script.

```
function test() {

  const url = 'https://finviz.com/calendar.ashx';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);
  var table = [];

  for (var i = 2; i < 15; i += 3) {
    var tableData = $('body > div.content > div > div > table:nth-child(' + i + ')');
    var thead = tableData.find('th').toArray().map(el => $(el).text());
    var tcontents = tableData.find('td').toArray().map(el => $(el).text());
    var idx = tcontents.indexOf('No economic releases');
    if (idx > -1) {
      tcontents.splice(idx + 1, 0, '', '', '', '', '')// Add empty elemets to match number of table columns
    }
    else tcontents.slice(5);
    var tableContents = [], column = 9;
    while (tcontents.length) tableContents.push(tcontents.splice(0, column)); //Convert 1D array to 2D array

    var table = [...table, ...[thead], ...tableContents]
  }

  console.log(table)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `for (var i = 2; i < 15; i += 3) {` and `var tableData = $('body > div.content > div > div > table:nth-child(' + i + ')');` looks overly rigid, likely to break if the page changes even a little bit. Why not loop over `$(".content table")` which is specific enough but not overly so? In general, there are a lot of hardcoded values here like `5`, `9`, `'', '', '', '', ''` and so forth, all of which can easily break. Is GAS allergic to `flatMap`? I see you're using spread. I'm not sure why you're using `var` when you have `const`, much safer.

Comment: Thank you for your good suggestions!  I admit mine is not ideal and I don't have enough coding skill to loop $(".content table") and use flatMap.  I wish a real example.

Comment: `flatMap` isn't too complex, it just turns `[[a], [b, c]]` into `[a, b, c]`, like `.map().flat()`. It's combining all tables into a 2d CSV-style array. I'm glad your code works for you, just minor notes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any sub tables (tables inside of other tables) here, nor do I see `'table[class="calendar"]'`. In general, avoid `[class=...]` syntax since it's ultra-rigid and fails if there are other classes present, or the classes are in a different order. Prefer `table.calendar`.

Try using nesting in your scraping to preserve the structure. `while` and `splice` are slidelines, not usually used for much of anything. `map` is the primary array transformation tool.

To write a CSV in Node:

```js
const {writeFile} = require("node:fs/promises");
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12
const Papa = require("papaparse"); // ^5.4.1

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$(".content table")].flatMap(e => {
      const headers = [...$(e).find("th")].map(e =>
        $(e).text().trim()
      );
      const rows = [...$(e).find("tr:has(td)")].map(e =>
        [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text().trim())
      );
      return [headers, ...rows, []];
    });
    return writeFile("out.csv", Papa.unparse(data));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Converted to GAS:

```js
function test() {
  const url = "<Your URL>";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);
  const data = [...$(".content table")].flatMap(e => {
    const headers = [...$(e).find("th")].map(e =>
      $(e).text().trim()
    );
    const rows = [...$(e).find("tr:has(td)")].map(e =>
      [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text().trim())
    );
    return [headers, ...rows, []];
  });
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.   Your codes didn't work in my Google Apps Script.  I should've mentioned I'm using Google Apps Script.  I figured out a solution as I posted here again, though my codes are not as neat as yours.

Comment: I don't use GAS, just Node. I've adjusted your tags accordingly--this is an important detail. Can you give a precise error message describing what "didn't work"? It's probably a syntactical issue, like GAS not understanding spread syntax or something, easily fixable. Otherwise, if you solved the problem, please post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help future visitors with the same problem as you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this with inbuilt formula `IMPORTHTML` to extract each table, providing appropriate indexes and then use `REDUCE` to merge the multiple 2D arrays:

```
=REDUCE(
  IMPORTHTML("<url>","table",6),
  SEQUENCE(10,1,7),
  LAMBDA(a,c,
    VSTACK(a,
      IMPORTHTML("<url>","table",c)
    )
  )
)
```